# jQuery accordion with href and collapsible

Tags: jquery, href, accordion, expand, multi-level

I'm working on an accordion menu with href link and collapsible header.
The problem is, it collapse the parent when I click the the child accordion. Are there any workaround?

```
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="acc-header" href="http://www.google.com">menu - level 1</a>
    <h3>+</h3>
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li>
        <a class="acc-header" href="http://www.google.com">menu - level 2-1</a>
      <h3>+</h3>
        <ul class="accordion">menu - level 3</ul>
      </li>
      <li>menu - level 2-2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
      header: "h3",
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "content",
      active: false,
      icons: false,
      animate: 200,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the updated version and it's working. The solution is to use the "`event.stopPropagation()`"(as @Renan Araújo mentioned) and remove the header setting on accordion.

https://codepen.io/CocoSkin/pen/vRQyZP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The according was closing because of the click event that was bubled from the anchor element.

Use stop propagation to prevent the bubling from the anchor:

```
$( ".accordion a" ).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I suggest you to read about event bubbling and check [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method.